# Chain rule of multivarible function.

Tags: real-analysis

If $u=x^{4}f(y/x,z/x)$ then I have to show that $xu_{x}+yu_{y}+zu_{z}=4u.$ How to prove it? $u_{x}=4x^{3}f(y/x,z/x)+x^{4}f_{p}p_{x}+f_{q}q_{y}$ if $p=y/x,q=z/x$. Now how to proceed further. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: That should be $q_x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just careful expansion: 
$$
t = x u_x + y u_y + u_z = 4x^4 f(p,q) + x^4( x f_p p_x + x f_q q_x + y f_p p_y + y f_q q_y + z f_p p_z + z f_q q_z)
$$
Further
$$
p_x = -y/x^2, p_y = 1/x, p_z = 0 \\
q_x = -z/x^2, q_y = 0, q_z = 1/x
$$
So
$$
t = 4x^4 f(p,q) + x^4(-(y/x)f_p -(z/x)f_q + (y/x)f_p + (z/x) f_q) = 4u
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** It may be helpful to think of $f(x_1,x_2)$ where $$x_1=x_1(x,y,z)=y/x$$ $$x_2=x_2(x,y,z)=z/x$$

Then, for example, $$u_x=4x^3f(x_1,x_2) + x^4\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x}[f(x_1,x_2)]$$ Now compute $$\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x}[f(x_1,x_2)] =f_1(x_1,x_2)\tfrac{\partial x_1}{\partial x} + f_2(x_1,x_2)\tfrac{\partial x_2}{\partial x}$$
and you should be able to take it from here. ($u_y$ and $u_z$ are similar, but won't involve the product rule).

Comment: I know upto your hint as I mention in my question...its not the solution..